# Crystal Reports:Hide/suppress field in report depending on user input/parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

So I have attached a picture of my app below. What I have is a Winforms C# app where the user can generate a barcode. He enters the parameters on the left, clicks Generate, and the Crystal Report is shown on the right with the barcode in a 4x12 format. I created the report template manually, i.e added Blob fields on the report in the positions I wanted through trial and error, and when the user clicks generate, it simply passes the image to the report.

[image]

I plan on adding a facility where the user can choose which slots on the report to actually generate an image, because perhaps he doesn't want to print 48 barcodes at a time. So maybe a checkboxes or something where the user will determine at runtime how the report will generate.

So my question is, what is the best way to do this? I was thinking of passing a list of the desired slots to the report as a parameter, and hiding or suppressing the fields depending on the list, but I don't know how to do this. My Crystal reports knowledge isn't the greatest. I only found ways to suppress data in cases of duplicate data, but I have a somewhat unique case where there isn't much info out there.

Answer (score 4):

to suppress an item using some condition I do it as follow:

1. select the item (that could be suppressed based on the condition)
2. right click on the item
3. select "Format Field" or "Format Text"
4. in the tab menu select "Common"
5. in the common tab look for Suppress (it is a checkbox) and check it  the click on the button that have a x+2 and a pencil,
6. write your condition
7. you may do it the other way around (unchecked textbox and condition to hide)

an example of mine: (?official is a parameter I sent)

IF {?Official} = true THEN

```
true
```

ELSE

```
false
```

Comment: You have led me on the right track. Thank you. So I need to create parameters for each field. Is it possible to pass 1 parameter as a list of bools, rather than 48 individual parameters for each field?

Comment: I don't think i have the answer for that, i can only think of (an absurd way)sending one integer and make a condition in every item :/  IF {?param1 >= 1} THEN true ELSE false, and the in the next one  {?param1 >= 2} THEN true.., to 48.., but there must be a better way to do it